# Win10 Virtual desktop в отдельном окне

Tags: java, c++, winapi

Есть ли способ отобразить созданный рабочий стол(win+tab->создать раб стол) в масштабируемом окне.
Цель - создать приложение в котором будет второй рабочий стол в отдельном окне отображатся на первом раб столе, поддерживающий взаимодействия с юзером (в основном для просмотра видео развернутого на фулскрин на 2 рабочем столе).

Comment: А что мешает пользователю просто смотреть видео в обычном окне? Виртуальные рабочие столы просто задают фильтрацию окон, отображаемых на (настоящем) рабочем столе.

Comment: суть в том чтобы смотреть видео в браузере который в отдельном окне и при режиме фулскрина видео оставалось в окне

Comment: А что мешает пользователю просто смотреть видео (пусть потоковое) в видео плеере?

Comment: Отсутствие на каждом сайте ссылок на видео-поток и адекватного плеера(пробовал VLC и MPC-BE) для потокового видео?

Comment: Так и на весь экран разворачивать не на каждом сайте можно.

Comment: На большинстве сайтов с плеерами для просмотра видео есть режим фулскрина.